# how to use htmlPlugin and workbox plugin in webpack for asp.core angular app

Tags: webpack, asp.net-core, angular5, service-worker, angular-universal

below is my configuration in webpack.config.js
 for generating service worker

```
       plugins: [new CheckerPlugin(), 
        new cleanPlugin([dist]),
        new htmlPlugin({
          filename: '/Home/Index',
          title: 'Get Started With Workbox For Webpack'
        }),
        new workboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
          swDest: 'sw.js',
          clientsClaim: true,
          skipWaiting: true,
        })
```

service worker is generated.but not registered.pls help me to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you figure it out? I guess you can try registering service worker after angular app is bootstrapped as explained in Registering Service Worker section of this article. 
https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/using-workbox-2-and-angular-5-to-create-a-progressive-web-app-part-1-app-shell-b14f9872384a#7b33

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need to register the service worker yourself as workbox will not do this for us. On your page the below script should do this:

```
<!--Register the service worker-->
<script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)

        })
        .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)

    })
}
</script>
```